# Serial communication - previously sent information incorrectly stored in image buffer arrays

Tags: timing, serial-bus

https://github.com/StonedEdge/Retro-Lite-CM4-Dock/tree/main

Hi everyone,

I am trying to read in some image data over serial communications, which is done on the trigger after receiving some characters over serial. Currently, my project is using a Raspberry Pi Pico for the receiver end and the transmitter is a Pi 4, sending data via some python scripts & aims to acheive the following objectives over serial communications:

a) Pico drives an OLED display over SPI with a splashscreen stored in flash, until an "X\n" character is received over serial. It then switches over to b)

b) Pico receives statistics information from the Pi 4 and begins  displays statistics on the OLED after receiving the above "X\n" character, looping/updating the display every 5 seconds

c) Display an image on the OLED once the "start\n" character is received (i.e when the get_image.py script is run and a game is started, this character is sent). After this character is successfully received by the Pico, execute SSD1351_get_image() function to read in image data over the serial port and store all three images in separate buffers below.

uint8_t boxart_buffer[IMAGE_SIZE_BYTES] = {0x00};
uint8_t combined_buffer[IMAGE_SIZE_BYTES] = {0x00};
uint8_t consol_buffer[IMAGE_SIZE_BYTES] = {0x00};

d) When a game is exited, run game_end.py and send character "END\n" to switch back to the stats view on the OLED

I have succesfully dumped the bin information pre-serial transmission and also after serial transmission to compare the two - the serial transmission is currently done via 3 python scripts on the transmitter side - get_image.py, splash_statistics.py & game_end.py. What I am finding is that the image buffer is containing information from the previous transfer. For example, when I dump the memory information of where the image data is stored (currently just sending a turquoise blue image as a test). The first bytes are read as 42 35 38 2E 39 43 0A 43 32 32 30 30 4D 48 7A 0A which translates to the below in ASCII characters. Sometimes I am finding that other characters are also read, like 58 0A, which equates to X\n in ASCII.

B58.9C
C2200MHz

Would anyone have the time to help me understand how I can improve my serial handling in the above code, such that I only read in the image data into my 3 buffers and not the control characters (i.e "start\n", "X\n" or the statistics data when a game is started (i.e when the get_image.py script is run)? I would like to basically wait until these transfers of control characters are fully complete, and then once done, send over the image data (3 x 32768 byte images for RGB565) (ensuring that these are not left in the serial data pipeline).

Any help would be greatly appreciated (from a guy who would appreciate a bit of help learning about serial communications to help my project on its way!)

Thank you. I have attached the relevant code below to my issue but feel free to take a look through the GitHub code as well.

Transmitter (Pi 4) - Python

```
while True:
    # Wait for game launch event file to be created
    while not os.path.exists(GAME_START_FILE):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    while not os.path.exists('/tmp/retropie-oled.log'):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    get_img_directories()

    pico_ports = pico_com_port()

    for port in pico_ports:
        # Send combined image to Pico
        get_combined_image()
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 921600)
        ser.write(b"s\n")
        ser.write(b"start\n")
        data = open("combined.bin", "rb")
        ser.write(data.read())
        data.close()
        ser.close()
        
        # Send boxart image to Pico
        get_boxart_image()
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 921600)
        ser.write(b"box\n")
        data = open("boxart.bin", "rb")
        ser.write(data.read())
        data.close()
        ser.close()
        
        # Send consol image to Pico
        get_consol_image()
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 921600)
        ser.write(b"consol\n")
        data = open("consol.bin", "rb")
        ser.write(data.read())
        data.close()
        ser.close()

    # Remove the game start file
    os.remove(GAME_START_FILE)
    time.sleep(5)
    break
```

Receiver (Pi Pico) - C

```
bool receive_start_string() {
  char start_str[] = "start\n";
  int start_str_index = 0;
  int data;

  while (start_str_index < strlen(start_str)) {
      data = getchar();
      if (data == start_str[start_str_index]) {
          start_str_index++;
      } else {
          start_str_index = 0;
      }
  }
  return true;
}

      // Check if the string is 'start'
      if (receive_start_string()) {
          stats_thread_running = false;
          multicore_reset_core1();
          SSD1351_clear_8();
          SSD1351_get_image(combined_buffer); 
          SSD1351_display_image(combined_buffer);
          button_thread_running = true;
          multicore_launch_core1(button_loop);
      }

void SSD1351_get_image(uint8_t buf[OLED_BUF_SIZE]) {
  SSD1351_clear();
  uint32_t i = 0;
  while (i < (DRAM_SIZE_8) {
    int data = getchar_timeout_us(10000);
    if (data != PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT) {
      buf[i++] = data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest) site.